# Facebook profile picture rate limit client vs. server

Tags: facebook, mongodb, denormalization

Although asked multiple times by users, I still feel uncomfortable with the theory behind.

I am using mongodb as a database for storing certain activities created by users (authenticated via facebook). For efficiency reasons, I want to store their profile picture URL along with the event (de-normalization in a event collection).

When the events are fetched from the database (by random visitors of my website), the profile pictures are rendered client side via:

```
<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/USERID/picture">
```

- no access-token (due to security on the client side)
- preferably lazy loaded...

For my understanding, the rate limit would become a problem, when I would do multiple request to the same profile picture server-side without passing an access token. (same request from same IP address)

Does the rate limit count against IP addresses? If so, only website visitors that
overrun the rate limit would have a problem whereas the same picture would still render just fine for other website visitors (different IP address) - is this correct?

To sum up:

- server side requests to the graph API should be made with an access token (this applies the rate to an individual user... necessary because 1 server IP)
- client side requests are made from different IP addresses anyway... so no access token required since every client (different IP address) counts against the individual limit

Are these assumptions correct?

Comment: Having same problem.... did you find out the answer?

Comment: @EugeneMi I have gone with the client solution... works fine so far

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely wanted to nab those profile pictures you could do so client side as well. You could use a javascript file uploader and upload an off-screen facebook profile picture to your servers. Each user of your application could do some of the uploading for you.

Probably a huge violation of someone's terms of service, but an interesting thought experiment.